# Tailwind CSS class not applying on chrome, working on firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, tailwind-css

I am maintaining a blog using Jekyll and Tailwind, and today I came up a very frustrating issue. I am normally using:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./assets/css/main.css -o ./assets/css/tailwind.css --watch
bundle exec jekyll serve --port 4001 --livereload
```

to set up my project and view it locally on the latest (just now) Chrome and Mac OS 13.1. I've had no issues making changes to the source that automatically propagate to what I'm served, until today when adding classes stopped working on Chrome, even after re-install, but are working on Firefox which I installed now just for this reason (it took some time for me to try another browser).

There are two astonishing elements to this issue:

1. When saving a change in the source code, I can see it flashing with the correct CSS on Chrome but then in an instant, it reverts back to not applying the Tailwind classes correctly.

[image]

2. Inspecting the element shows that the class is indeed correctly read, but the CSS to be applied due to the Tailwind class is not found in the Developer Tools, as shown in the image below (before). When reverting to another style that seems to work, it is correctly applied (after).

- **Before**

  [image]
- **After**

  [image]

Any ideas as to why this happens or what to try?

Comment: At some point, the issue resolved itself as mysteriously as it first occurred. The question still stands, however, as the culprit cannot be traced. I am not aware if some sort of flash update to Chrome has been published in the meantime.

Comment: And back again for more...

Comment: Your CSS load order is important, the last css taking precendence.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Thanks for the comment, but I believe this is irrelevant. This issue relates to two different browsers and the same CSS (but Firefox works), and was a problem that came and went. I am not sure if something was patched for Chrome that fixed it.

Comment: It's difficult to tell since you haven't provided much of your code.